# dict as value for YAML key in an Ansible task

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am unable to figure out how to pass a dictionary/hash-map of key-value pairs as the value for an option in an ansible tasks.

### Default Options:

```
# roles/ec2/defaults/main.yml
ec2:
    key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
    instance_type: m3.medium
    image: ami-xxxx
    group_id: sg-xxxxx
    vpc_subnet_id: subnet-xxxxx
    region: us-east-1
    wait: yes
    instance_tags:
        Name: "{{ env_name }}-{{ group_name }}-{{ ansible_date_time.epoch }}"
        Type: "{{ env_name }}-{{ group_name }}-{{ ansible_date_time.epoch }}"
```

### Attempt 1

```
# roles/ec2/tasks/main.yml
- name: launch single instance
  ec2: "{{ ec2 }}"
  register: instance
```

#### Stacktrace

```
fatal: [localhost] => Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/1.8.2/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 590, in _executor
    exec_rc = self._executor_internal(host, new_stdin)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/1.8.2/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 792, in _executor_internal
    return self._executor_internal_inner(host, self.module_name, self.module_args, inject, port, complex_args=complex_args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/1.8.2/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 994, in _executor_internal_inner
    num_args_post = self._count_module_args(module_args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/1.8.2/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 434, in _count_module_args
    vargs = split_args(args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/1.8.2/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/module_utils/splitter.py", line 73, in split_args
    args = args.strip()
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

### Attempt 2

```
# roles/ec2/tasks/main.yml
- name: launch single instance
  ec2: "{{ ec2 | to_nice_yaml }}"
  register: instance
```

#### Stacktrace

```
failed: [localhost] => {"failed": true}
msg: this module requires key=value arguments (['assign_public_ip:', 'true', 'group_id:', 'sg-xxxxx', 'image:', 'ami-xxxxx', 'instance_tags:', 'Environment:', 'stage', 'Name:', 'stage-analytics-stack', 'Type:', 'analytics-stack', 'instance_type:', 'm3.medium', 'key_name:', '2014-10-xxxxxx', 'region:', 'us-east-1', 'vpc_subnet_id:', 'subnet-xxxxx', 'wait:', 'true
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain what you are trying to accomplish, but I don't think it works that way. Maybe this is what you want?

```
- name: launch single instance
  ec2: key_name="{{ ec2.key_name }}" ...
```

The `ec2` in your `roles/ec2/defaults/main.yml` is just a variable name (and I would name it differently in order to avoid confusion with the `ec2` module). The `to_nice_yaml` filter isn't meant to do what you are trying.

Comment: That is currently what I have, but not what I want because then I need to duplicate all of my options. **Attempt 1** would be the ideal way.

Comment: @MarkFeltner As far as I know this is not possible.